# What date format is this? /Date(-62135575200000-0600)/

Tags: php, datetime, date

I'm consuming an API (XML output) with PHP and it is returning all timestamps in the following format. Believe it or not this isn't in the docs anywhere.

Is this a standard date format?
What format is this timestamp in?
How can I convert it to a unix timestamp in PHP?

/Date(-62135575200000-0600)/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the default JSON format of date.

Comment: Spot on. . More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a .NET Date string, which would mean that it is milliseconds since 1970, and the timezone.